# Error when attempting UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, active-directory

I'm trying to get all the active directory roles associated to the user using a website in intranet.

The website uses a webapi REST service to perform this operation.

I get an error while getting the UserPrincipal:

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
    principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN"), "USERNAME");
}
```

The error I get is the following:
"Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

This does not happen when trying the website from my pc (on local IIS).

It only happens when:

1. I'm using the website published on the server from my pc
2. I'm conneted in remote desktop to the server and using the website on localhost (??)

I already set on IIS ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication on true, and Anonymous Authentication on false.

Last thing: if I try to use the website published on my computer from the remote desktop it works.

Do you have any ideas?